# Difference between Fragment and MainActivity java code?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am making a BMI calculator app on **android studio** and for starters I just want this code to work:

```
        edit_height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_height);
        edit_weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_weight);
        button_calculate_bmi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_calculate_bmi);
        text_results = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_results);

        button_calculate_bmi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                    String results = "Results:";
                 //   int height = Integer.parseInt(edit_height.getText().toString());
                   results += "hey I clicked a button!";
                   text_results.setText(results);
            }
        });
```

*(I know that id doesn't calculate but I just want it to work and after that i will continue the code)*

the problem is that this code is made for `ActivityMain` but my BMI calculator is on a different fragment.
what can I do to make this work?
Can I write the code on  `ActivityMain` and then link it? Or make the changes to the code and put it on the fragment?
Thanks in advance.

I have declared the variable in the start of the code like so:

````
    TextView text_results;
    EditText edit_height, edit_weight;
    Button button_calculate_bmi;  ```
````

Comment: You only needs to attach the fragment and call in the activity. I posted  a code, check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to add the fragment and call

```
val fragment = ExampleFragment()
// YOur fragment's container and fragment's name
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
fragmentTransaction.commit()
```

// Your main's activity needs a FrameLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This link permits to understand what i am talking

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

Comment: so I write your code above to the `activityMain` and everything else is the same?
(Sorry if my question is stupid i am very new to android studio)

Comment: not problem, in your xml, you need to add a FrameLayout and call it

Comment: Thanks that link helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can write your BMI calculator code in another class, then you reuse that function in wherever you want (no matter `Activity` or `Fragment`)

```
public class Utils {
    public static float BMICalculate(int weight, int height) {
        // calculate your result

        return result;
    }
}
```

and in your activity:

```
button_calculate_bmi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
            String results = "Results:";
            //   int height = Integer.parseInt(edit_height.getText().toString());

            results += Utils.BMICalculate(weight, height);
            text_results.setText(results);
    }
});
```

Comment: he needs  to call the fragment, because the main activity does not have the code and view

Comment: I found it with a little bit of snooping around on alejandros link but thanks a lot I will keep this in mind! I appreciate it